# What are usable databinding libraries for Swing?

Tags: java, swing, data-binding

Something that can do two-way bean synchronization with components, and also more fancy (advanced) stuff?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is also the [JGoodies Binding](https://binding.dev.java.net/) project. The author has a fairly detailed [presentation](http://www.jgoodies.com/articles/binding.pdf) on it.

It works using PropertyChangeListeners, if I recall correctly. I haven't used it myself, but other developers in my workplace have experimented with it and had fairly positive impressions.

Comment: A looked in to this stuff a couple of years ago and all the options jgoodies was the most complete. It does require PropertyChangeListene's to be supported on your beans, but then all the others did too.

Comment: Try http://www.jgoodies.com/downloads/libraries.html - latest bindings release was Dec 2010, so it looks like it's still alive - maybe the java.net project side is dead.

Answer (score 2):

Well, there's the [Beans Binding](https://beansbinding.dev.java.net/) project, for starters. There's an example on [java.net](http://weblogs.java.net/pub/a/2008/03/20/synchronizing-properties-with-beans-binding.html). If you use NetBeans, there's support [built in](http://www.netbeans.org/kb/60/java/gui-binding.html).

Answer (score 0):

You need to get Hitch.....

http://hitch.silvermindsoftware.com/